# Some quicker methods to decide for or against normality .

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

When testing for normality of a  group apart from using the method of using generating sets E.G. If A is a generating set for G and B is a generating set for H then we must check if $bab^{-1}, b^{-1}ab$, (which cuts the work down a little but is still quite tediuous. ).

Is there some quick ways to decide for or against normality . I know a few , for instance in a nilpotent group the maximal subgroups are always normal, or groups of index two are always normal. I also know that in general this is quite an intractable question but I was hoping someone might know of some quick ways to decide normality that I'm unaware of. Particularly in deciding if a group is not normal as I know no tricks at all for deciding that.

Comment: One often proves a subgroup is normal by finding an explicit homomorphism that has that subgroup as its kernel. (Yes, a subgroup is normal if and only if it is the kernel of a homomorphism, but the point here is to have some “natural” homomorphism that happens to have your subgroup as the kernel). For example, the sign map $\sigma\colon S_n\to\{1,-1\}$ that maps odd permutations to $-1$ and even permutations to $1$ shows you that $A_n\triangleleft S_n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what about deciding if a subgroup is not normal though ? Is there a better way than just checking with the method described above ?

Comment: Apart from artificial questions like "Find the normal subgroups of this group.." is this ever a real question?

Comment: @ancientmathematician well I was thinking in the context of Galois theory where it becomes important to know which groups are normal and which aren't

Comment: Thanks. (I suppose one might test by looking at the corresponding extension? :-)  ).

Comment: @ancientmathematician good point +1

Answer (score 1):

If a subgroup is normal then it must be a (disjoint) union of $G$-conjugacy classes (the converse is not true). So if conjugacy classes are known (not hard to find them), then you can check against them.

Comment: For instance a standard exercise is to find the conjugacy classes of $ A_5$ and then show it is a simple group.

Comment: Yes that is an excellent example, +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that a subgroup $H < G$ is *not* normal, you simply have to find one element $g \in G$ such that $gHg^{-1} \ne H$. It often happens that through intuition or experience or whatever, you can guess the right $g$, and then prove the inequality $g H g^{-1} \ne H$ quite easily.

In fact, sometimes normality fails so spectacularly that *any* element $g \in G-H$ satisfies $g H g^{-1} \ne H$. Such subgroups are called *malnormal*. As an example, in a rank 2 free group $F$ with free basis $a,b$, the subgroup generated by $a$ is malnormal.